Using fzero to solve for extinction angle in MatLAB
I am trying to find the best way to use Matlab to find the extinction angle for a single phase full wave controller. I have seen people create a graph that shows the intersection of two lines which they use as the angle. An example problem would be using the following parameters:
Vs = 100sin(2000pit); r = 20; L = 33mH; a = 40o.
I understand the extinction angle is 291o or so by using calculation methods but it seems it would be much easier to use the fzero method I have seen.
Thank you in advance.
